# Identify shower diverter valve (switch)

Tags: shower, diverter

Good day to all,

Dear community, please, try to help me.

I bought a freestanding shower faucet but the shower/faucet switch broke and now I'm having trouble finding a replacement. I know that this mixer is very common in Poland.

[image]

This is how the small switch looks like, because there are models with a large switch

[image]

As a result, without any reason, the regulator flew out of its seat and, as you can see in the picture, broke

[image]

Comment: Looks like the back part of the diverter valve broke off, probably is still inside the housing.  Can you remove it?  Or maybe small pieces of it fell into the plumbing.  That would be bad.  You have no docs/warranty?

Comment: Unfortunately, but no any docs or warranty. I will try to remove the back part of the diverter valve today. I've tried to contact with supplier, but they are very very lazy and don't answer anything specific.

Comment: Hmm .. there is nothing in your hand that shows how that thing would be installed.  No threads, no screw sticking out the back.  So I wonder if the broken part is threaded, and  still screwed into the valve body?  If so it won't be fun to remove.

Answer (score -1):

Finally i've received an answer from the supplier:

[image]

[image]

I hope that this information will help someone to resolve the same problem.

Thanks to all for your help and understanding, wish you all the best.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: They sent you these pictures but they won't send you the new part?

Comment: Now you can see how to remove the broken part.  The second set of holes (the left set in  your last picture) are broken in half.  The part that is still inside the body is screwed in, as you can now see, and the broken holes should provide a way for you to grab it and unscrew it.  A pair of needle nose pliers might work   Or in fact, the broken part that you have might work to engage the broken part that is still inside, using a wrench to turn it.

Comment: Who's the supplier? Did they give you a part number? This answer doesn't really provide anything useful.